# How to Stop Form Submit on jquery.post call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, post

#### html

```
<form action="/jobseeker/profile/" method="post" id="langForm">     
    <input type="hidden" name="curform" value="langform">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Language Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="languageadd" maxlength="120" name="language" type="text" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

#### jquery script

```
$("#langForm").on("submit", function(event){    
    $.post('/jobseeker/profile/', $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
        alert('AJAX successful');
        //CreateRow(jdata);
    }, "json"); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

#### views.py for /jobseeker/profile/

```
def addlang(request):
    #curform=request.POST['curform']
    md=Languages()
    for i in request.POST.keys():
        if i=='curform':continue
        setattr(md,i,request.POST[i])
    md.save()
    n={ 
            "pk": md.pk,
            "lang":md.language,
            "read":md.read,
            "speak":md.speak,
            "write":md.write            
    }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(n), mimetype="application/json")
```

#### when i click submit button prevent default not working and whole form submittion takes place

[image: after submit button click]

Comment: is there any error in the browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxForm'

Comment: @ArunPJohny `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxForm' localhost:8000/jobseeker/profile/:236
(anonymous function) localhost:8000/jobseeker/profile/:236
c jquery.js:3
p.fireWith jquery.js:3
b.extend.ready jquery.js:3
H`

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry i have some typo error ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with return false;

```
 $("#langForm").on("submit", function(event){    
 $.post('/jobseeker/profile/', $(this).serialize(),
 function(data){
    alert('AJAX successful');
    //CreateRow(jdata);
 }, "json"); 
 return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry i have some typo. it is working now. now i checked with `return false;` it is working. also i checked `preventDefault` it is also working fine. is there any difference between both

Comment: return false  is equivalent to calling both, e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation. prevent default just prevent the deafult behaviuor like form submission and does not affect event flow. in this case `event.preventDefault()` also works so does return false

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `action="/jobseeker/profile/"` specified in your HTML form.

Try this

```
$("#langForm").submit(function(event){    
    $.post('/jobseeker/profile/', $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        alert('AJAX successful');
        //CreateRow(jdata);
    }, "json"); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

event.preventDefault(); will stop the default submit of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Put `preventDefault()` on top and `return false` in the end.

```
$("#langForm").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/jobseeker/profile/', $(this).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            alert('AJAX successful');
            //CreateRow(jdata);
        }, "json");
    return false;
});
```